# HP Trim data migration to SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online

how can HP trim Data can be migrated to SharePoint online,
Is their any tool ?

How it can be possible

Answer (score 0):

We used TRIMBocX solution to integrate HP TRIM and SharePoint O365 and keeping it insync. You can use the same for migrating HP TRIM to SharePoint Online O365. TRIMBocX suite is capable of connecting to legacy HP TRIM and new HP RM with SharePoint On premises and Online.

Answer (score 0):

There are vendors out there that supply tools and consultancy to do this (I work for one so I'll avoid posting links). It's not cheap so make sure you are getting exactly what you want.

If you are still within your support period speak to HP as they do have some export tools that work quite well and then you only have to worry about getting content into SharePoint.

If you are outside of you support period and you have a competent dev team you can do this yourself. Avoid the APIs and go straight to the DB as the TRIM schema is not overly complex. You can then extract the relevant metadata and the binaries to a file share and move them into SP from there.